# Prepending table name to column returns unknown column error

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I'm having trouble with a select statement. I'm trying to execute a join and I need to prepend the table names to the columns but it throws an error of `unknown column user_roles.name in field list`.

### Original query:

```
db.query(
    "SELECT user_role.name, user_role.description, user_role_admin.permission FROM user_role ur INNER JOIN user_role_admin ura ON ura.user_id = ? AND ura.role_id = ur.role_id",
[param],
function (req, res, next) {
    if (error) throw error;

    if (rows.length > 0) {
        res.json(rows);
    } else {
        res.sendStatus(500);
    }
}
```

It is definitely a column because if I try the following query I get values from the table.

```
SELECT name, description FROM user_role;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have given the table names aliases.  Use them:

```
SELECT ur.name, ur.description, ura.permission
FROM user_role ur INNER JOIN
     user_role_admin ura
     ON ura.user_id = ? AND ura.role_id = ur.role_id;
```

Once you give the table an alias, the original table name is not recognized.

Comment: That's interesting, I thought I would have to use the full names before I defined the alias. Is there a reason why it was designed this way because you would think the alias and the full table name are still accepted.

Comment: @Mr.Smithyyy . . . The same table could appear multiple times in the `FROM` clause.  More importantly, having two different names for the same reference would be quite confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Use alias instead of full table name:

```
SELECT ur.name, ur.description, ura.permission 
FROM user_role ur --when alliased you cannot use original name
INNER JOIN user_role_admin ura 
   ON ura.user_id = ? 
  AND ura.role_id = ur.role_id
```